# How many colors will be used in the following bipartite graph

Tags: graphs, colorings

I decided to create an algorithm to find the colors that is used to color a bipartite graph, the algorithm proceeds as follows:

- Rename the vertices in a some order $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$.
- Do a single pass through all vertices of the graph, starting from $v_1$.
- To each $v_i$ assign the smallest available color not used among its already colored neighbors.

Now I have consider the following graph, $K_{4,4}$:

[image]

The question, I have is that, I have ordered the vertices in the graph. How many colors will be
used here? The algorithm is giving me 7, I don't know why?

One very important question that I have is,
will the change in orderings, would get the maximum and minimum colors? I think yes, but I am not getting it.

Comment: I think there is a problem in your test, because your algorithm should find two colors used in your graph, not seven. And actually, since your graph is [complete bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph), your algorithm should always find two colors, no matter the ordering (I think this can be shown by induction).

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is known as [greedy coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring), and its properties are well-known.

When run on a complete bipartite graph, it always produces a 2-coloring (this is a nice exercise).